# How to find a value across multiple columns, and return the value at the top of the column which the value is in

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would be grateful for help with this query, it got me stumped!

How would I find out what City name is at the top of a column containing the name of a town which I am searching for? There are multiple columns containing sets of towns, with Cities listed at the top of each column.

[image]

Comment: Just to get a better understanding of what you want, I gotta ask some questions. 1)How do you "search for" the city name? CTRL+F? ---- 2) Are there empty cells within the city-town-array?

Comment: The towns are listed on a separate tab, so I will be returning the result 'City' in an adjacent row to the list of towns.
There are no empty cells, its a block of data . The picture attached to the question above is a snapshot of what the full array looks like.

Answer (score 0):

This is an array formula:

```
=INDEX(Cities[#Headers],1,MAX((Town=Cities[#Data])*COLUMN(Cities)-MIN(COLUMN(Cities))+1))
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

I used a **Table** which I re-named `Cities` and structured references.  You can change them to absolute references, but named references seem simpler.

You type in the name of a `Town` and it will return the Header for the found column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**To get the Column Heading based on the value in Data Range, you need to use this simple Formula:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter the Town Name in Cell `A221` and Formula 
  in `B221`.

`=INDEX($A$215:$D$215,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$216:$D$218=A$221)*(COLUMN($A$216:$D$218))))-COLUMN($A$216)+1)`

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*